# Xml validation against xsd accept wrong xml as valid

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have java code which validate my xml against xsd:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File("src/main/resources/file.xml"));

    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new Source[] {
            new StreamSource(new File("src/main/resources/RegTypy.xsd")),
            new StreamSource(new File("src/main/resources/XopInclude.xsd")),
            new StreamSource(new File("src/main/resources/RobTypy.xsd")),
            new StreamSource(new File("src/main/resources/RobDotazyData.xsd")), });
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    try {
        validator.validate(xmlFile);
        System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
        System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Xsd for download are [here](http://www.szrcr.cz/uploads/Popisy_datovych_typu_v._8.03..zip): in root directory and in rob/xsd directory

now my xml looks like:

```
<data:RobCtiAifoData xmlns:ns2="urn:cz:isvs:rob:schemas:RobTypy:v1" xmlns:data="urn:cz:isvs:rob:schemas:RobDotazyData:v1" xmlns:reg="urn:cz:isvs:reg:schemas:RegTypy:v1">
    <data:Aifo stav="spravny" xsi:type="ns2:LokalniAifoStavType" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2</data:Aifo>
    <data:VyuzitiPoskytnuti>vyuziti</data:VyuzitiPoskytnuti>
</data:RobCtiAifoData>
```

important part from xsd is:

```
<xs:complexType name="RobCtiAifoDataType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="cs">Čtení referenčních údajů podle AIFO.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Aifo" type="reg:LokalniAifoType" />
        <!-- omezení - jenom využití nebo poskytnutí -->
        <xs:element name="VyuzitiPoskytnuti" type="rob:TypVyuzitiPoskytnutiType" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="znepristupniLog" type="xs:boolean" />
</xs:complexType>
```

as you can see Aifo should have type `reg:LokalniAifoType` but in xml it is overrided to ns2:LokalniAifoStavType which has additional parameter stav. Question is why this type is accepted in xml and why it is valid xml.

UPDATE:

```
<xs:complexType name="LokalniAifoType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="cs">Lokální identifikátor AIFO. Klíč typu integer.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:int">
            <xs:attribute name="prevodAifoStatus" type="PrevodAifoStatusType">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="cs">Informace o výsledku převodu v ORG, pokud se nepodařilo přeložit.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="stavOvereniAifo" type="xs:boolean">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation xml:lang="cs">Existence AIFO se má ověřit v ROB.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="LokalniAifoStavType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation xml:lang="cs">Agendový identifikátor fyzické osoby včetně stavu a času
            poslední změny.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="reg:LokalniAifoType">
            <xs:attribute name="stav" type="reg:StavType" />
            <xs:attribute name="zmenaCas" type="ZmenaCasType" />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Please show us as well the definition of the `reg:LokalniAifoType` and `ns2:LokalniAifoStavType` types.

Comment: you can find it in xsd but ok I add it to this question too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearly extending using `xs:extension` in `LokalniAifoStavType` ?  if an element specifies its of type `LokalniAifoType`, then any of the extended type of it can appear in the XML.

Comment: but why ? in xsd is defined parent. I dont want to accept  extended child here

Comment: This is like Java inheritance - "substitutability" - child can be used in any context where parent is used.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MuertoExcobito - I am not critiquing anything here; Just explaining why it is behaving so. To understand it fully xsd OP needs to read xsd extension etc. I can not type in details that are covered in pages of content else where as an answer. Hope you understand. I have edited my answer to make it clear.